# Is there a more efficient/elegant way to adjust line styles?

Tags: exam

I'm using the `exam` class and wanted to change the `\fillin` command so it produces a dotted line instead of a solid line. So I copied and pasted the command definition into my preamble and substituted `\dotfill` for `\hrule` in the appropriate place, like so:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter

\def\@fillin@relay[#1]{%
  % The first argument is in \fillin@ans, the second is #1.
  \leavevmode
  \ifprintanswers
    \rlap{\raise -\answerclearance \hbox to #1{\hrulefill}}%
    \begingroup
      \setbox0 \hbox{\color@begingroup
             \CorrectChoice@Emphasis \fillin@ans \color@endgroup}%
      \ifdim\wd0 > #1\relax
        \hbox{\CorrectChoice@Emphasis \fillin@ans}%
      \else
        \hbox to #1{\CorrectChoice@Emphasis \hfil \fillin@ans \hfil}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \else
    \raise -\answerclearance \hbox to #1{\dotfill}%
  \fi
}% @fillin@relay

\makeatother

\begin{document}


    \begin{questions}

    \question Because I was so tired I \fillin on the bed. (lay/laid)

    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

This works, but did I really need to add all that stuff to the preamble, or was there a better / more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
\documentclass{exam}


\newcommand\dotfillin{{\let\hrulefill\dotfill\fillin}}

\begin{document}


    \begin{questions}

    \question Because I was so tired I \dotfillin\ on the bed. (lay/laid)

    \end{questions}


  \end{document}
```

Comment: Why the trailing backslash on the new command?

Comment: @crmdgn as always in latex you need a `\ ` to get a space so the syntax should be`I \dotfill\ on` with a space either side or `I\dotfill on` with no space.